502 Bad gateway after deploying laravel on docker
Hello i'm trying to deploy my laravel app to Coolify and use Docker file here's what i have
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libonig-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libgd-dev
# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Update package list and install Nginx
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
# Remove default Nginx configuration
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

# Copy nginx.conf to /etc/nginx/sites-available as default
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-external-gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy Laravel application code
COPY . /var/www

# Run composer update
RUN composer update

# Run artisan commands
RUN php artisan package:discover --ansi
RUN php artisan optimize

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

currently the server is running but it says 502, i've tried solutions from chatgpt but still not working, anyone knows the issue?
I also have tried using nixpacks but has an issue when using php 8.2

A container only runs one process, and only the last CMD has an effect, so your container is running Nginx and not your PHP application.  If you need an Nginx proxy then it needs to run in a separate container.  (Most newer languages and frameworks can both run application code and serve static files from the same process and therefore can work in a single container.)

@DavidMaze serving laravel via integrated server is not suitable for production - in this case must be another container with nginx OR pass fastcgi port to external nginx.

As pointed out in the comments, you ideally should only have a single process running per container. However, you can run both PHP-FPM and NGINX in the same container as follows:

Create an entrypoint.sh script that launches PHP-FPM in the background and then runs NGINX.

#!/bin/sh

php-fpm -D

nginx -g 'daemon off;'


Set this as the entrypoint in your Dockerfile.

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]

